# Show remaining time in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, c#-4.0

I want to show a countdown timer in my application displaying the duration until a certain `NodaTime.Instant`. For this I have the following design:

```
public class Event
{
    private Instant EventStartTime;
    public Duration TimeLeft { get { return EventStartTime - SystemClock.Instance.Now; } }
}
```

But when I now show it like this in my view:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Event.TimeLeft}" />
```

This does not dynamically update. I know of the solution where I start a timer to continuously trigger `PropertyChangedEvents` but this seems like overkill in this situation.

Is there a clean way to always show the correct time left to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either raise the PropertyChanged event for the TimeLeft property whenever you want to the Label to get updated. This requires the Event class to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged event.

The other option would be to explicitly update the binding using a BindingExpression. You could then use a DispatcherTimer that calls the UpdateTarget() method of the BindingExpression every x seconds:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer timer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
    {
        var be = theLabel.GetBindingExpression(Label.ContentProperty);
        if (be != null)
            be.UpdateTarget();
    };
    timer.Start();
}
```

---

```
<Label x:Name="theLabel" Content="{Binding Event.TimeLeft}" />
```

There is no cleaner way to refresh a data binding in WPF.

Answer (score 1):

WPF relies on mechanisms notifying it when a property changes, the two being dependency properties or INotifyPropertyChanged events.

In your example, the Content property is set to it's initial value by the binding. However as the binding is never notified that the property value has changed, it never updates.

Hence the timer solution with `PropertyChanged` events is probably the best option.